# C++ shared_ptr call deconstructor of owned object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have this code

```
class TC
{
public:
   TC()
   {
        i_idx = s_idx++;
        Serial.printf("TC Construct %d\r\n", i_idx);
  };

  virtual ~TC()
  {
        Serial.printf("TC Deconstruct %d\r\n",i_idx);
  };

  int i_idx;
  static int s_idx;
};

int TC::s_idx = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.printf("\r\n\nSetup start\r\n");
    std::shared_ptr<TC> stc = std::make_shared<TC>(TC());
}

void loop()
{
}
```

When excuting I get the result :

```
Setup start
TC Construct 0
TC Deconstruct 0
TC Deconstruct 0
```

I expected that the deconstructor on TC would only be called once, when the shared_ptr goes out of scope.

Anyone knows the reason for the second call ?

Comment: the destruction of the copy made in the copy constructor, use `make_shared<TC>()`to avoid the copy.

Comment: You create a temporary to initialize your shared_ptr via move-construction (`make_shared<TC>(TC())`). That temporary is also destructed

Comment: Because you've coped object before putting it into smart pointer.  Add `TC(const TC&) = delete; TC& operator=(const TC&) = delete;` to prevent this behavior.

Comment: @VictorGubin But that will also prevent the code from compiling?

Comment: @songyuanyao exactly :) What would you prefer - compile time error, or unexpected program behavior at runtime ?

Comment: @VictorGubin Fine, I got what you meant.

Answer (score 8):

> Anyone knows the reason for the second call ?

Because two objects are constructed. With `std::make_shared<TC>(TC());`, a temporary `TC` is constructed by `TC()` firstly, then it's copied to construct the 2nd object which is managed by the `std::shared_ptr`.

You may add the copy/move constructor for more clear observation; you'll see twice construction and twice destruction. e.g.

```
class TC
{
public:
  TC()
  {
        i_idx = s_idx++;
        Serial.printf("TC Construct %d\r\n", i_idx);
  }

  TC(const TC&)
  {
        i_idx = s_idx++;
        Serial.printf("TC copy Construct %d\r\n", i_idx);
  }

  TC(TC&&)
  {
        i_idx = s_idx++;
        Serial.printf("TC move Construct %d\r\n", i_idx);
  }

  virtual ~TC()
  {
        Serial.printf("TC Deconstruct %d\r\n",i_idx);
  }

  int i_idx;
  static int s_idx;
};
```

BTW: For this case the temporary is needless, you might want just `std::make_shared<TC>();`.

Comment: My code snippet is a simplification of my code. I do need to use a  TC( vars ) constructor. Am I correct that I only can avoid the move_constructor is using f.e. std::shared_ptr<TC> stc (new TC(12))  (i.e. not using make_shared() ?

Comment: @hreintke If your class also have copy/move constructor then you'll see twice construction and twice destruction; which seems more clear and matches what I explained.